# How to use TypeScript with Vue.js and Single File Components?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, vue.js

I have searched all over the web for a minimal, working example of a Vue.js + TypeScript setup. As per usual with the "modern JavaScript stack", most of these tutorials are either out-of-date despite being written just a couple of months ago or depending on a very specific setup. There appears to be no generic, verifiable example to build on.

Here are some of the resources I considered:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html
- https://herringtondarkholme.github.io/2016/10/03/vue2-ts2/
- http://www.mindissoftware.com/Vue-Sample-in-Typescript/
- https://medium.com/@hayavuk/setting-vue-up-for-typescript-goodness-a6ddc4072f4f
- https://johnpapa.net/vue-typescript/
- https://alexjoverm.github.io/2017/06/28/Integrate-TypeScript-in-your-Vue-project/

The basic template I use is the one provided by running `vue-cli init webpack` with all default options. As this produces a lot of code, I'm not pasting everything here. If there is need for some specific excerpts, I will gladly update the question.

The official Vue.js documentation is useless for my purpose because it doesn't consider setting up TypeScript with SFCs. The latest I tried was the last on of the list. I followed the setup precisely but it runs me into the following error on `npm run dev`:

```
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/[REDACTED]/ts-test/src/main.ts(12,3)
      TS2345: Argument of type '{ el: string; router: any; template: string; components: { App: { name: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Rec...'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'router' does not exist in type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData<Vue>, DefaultMethods<Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Rec...'.
```

Can anyone shine some light on why this happens and how to resolve it? Better yet, I'd very much welcome a concise, minimal, step-by-step example of how to set up a working Vue.js + TypeScript configuration with the `webpack` template.

I have already successfully completed several client projects that run in production in Vue.js with vanilla JavaScript but this TypeScript tooling in combination with Vue.js just confuses the hell out of me.

Comment: hello here is a template with typescript hope its helps https://github.com/morganster/vue-ts-webpack-template

Comment: Unfortunately now, as it does not take care of the Vue Router part.

Comment: As it stands right now, all the examples are either bloated and complicated or don't take vue-router/vuex into account. I'm about to lose my patience with this setup. I will probably just drop it altogether and continue as I always have.

Comment: hello i just update the template with the vue-router part, check if it helps like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**update**

In Sep 2018, should try the new `vue-cli` with the [TypeScript Plugin](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-typescript).

---

Absolute agree @sobolevn's opinion. But, there is a lot of information for me to judge, community support for TypeScript is worth the wait.

Vue's ecosystem is being more TypeScript:

1. `*.vue` file's `TypeScript` lint in VSCode be supported. Look this issue [vetur](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/170).
2. Open Source Ecosystem.

   - [`vue-router`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/tree/dev/types)
   - [`vuex-class`](https://github.com/ktsn/vuex-class/)
   - [`vue-test-utils`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/tree/dev/types)
3. New `vue-cli` in design. [click me](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/pull/797)

So if you have time to wait, you can temporarily observe for some time. Or, you can refer to these projects: [TypeScript-Vue-Starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter) and [A Webpack Template Fork With Typescript Support](https://github.com/Toilal/vue-webpack-template).

Answer (score 7):

I have tried to use `typescript` with `vue`. My personal opinion: it does not work well. Since some `vue` internals are not suited for `typescript`:

1. `vuex` with `this.$store.dispatch('some_action')`
2. `Vue.use`, `Vue.mixin` and other similar things that mutate the global `Vue` instance

But, while doing my research I have found these wonderful boilerplates: [typescript-vue-tutorial](https://github.com/DanielRosenwasser/typescript-vue-tutorial/blob/master/src/components/Hello.vue) by Daniel Rosenwasser and [TypeScript-Vue-Starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter/blob/master/src/components/HelloDecorator.vue) by Microsoft.

I have also tried to mimic `vue-webpack-template` with `typescript` by myself: https://github.com/sobolevn/wemake-vue-template

There are also nice tools to make your `typescript` + `vue` workflow better:

- [`vuex-typescript`](https://github.com/istrib/vuex-typescript)
- [`vue-class-component`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component)
- [`vue-property-decorator`](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator)

In the end I have decided to use [`flow`](https://flow.org/en/docs/getting-started/). Check [this project template](https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-vue-template) if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks. That's an interesting observation as I got the impression from almost all of the posts and articles I've read that TypeScript + Vue.js would be a great match and TypeScript in particular would be great to use. So far all I can say is that it's frustrating. I don't see why I should spend hours on even getting my tooling to work.

Comment: @herrbischoff that was my biggest question too.

Comment: I have tried Flow but it produces errors when used in combination with the JavaScript/TypeScript Language Server. In Vim as well as VScode the language server complains about `// @flow` and the type declarations as being exclusive to TypeScript. Man, this whole JavaScript stack is just a smeggin' nightmare to work with... How about the community would take a deep breath, define working defaults, fixes what doesn't work and continue from there? It frustrates me to the point that I question whether I should do any frontend development **at all** any more.

Comment: Well, broken IDE support is not the worst thing you can have in modern frontend!

Answer (score 3):

This looks like the latest vue-cli template with a significant amount of stars and support for vue 2.5.

I don't think I saw it specifically mentioned in the other answers

`vue init ducksoupdev/vue-webpack-typescript my-project`

https://github.com/ducksoupdev/vue-webpack-typescript

Answer (score 1):

With the latest versions of VueJS it is possible to create a reliable & maintainable project with Vue, Typescript & JSX. I have created a boilerplate for starters at [Vue.TSX](https://github.com/tejzpr/Vue.TSX)